# Representing operators in the Glauber-Sudarshan P-representation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, homework-and-exercises, operators, quantum-optics

If $| \alpha >$ represents a coherent state (the normalized right eigenstate of the destruction operator $a$ in Quantum Mechanics; $\alpha$ is a complex number), then it is known that:

\begin{equation}
\int | \alpha >< \alpha| \frac{d^2\alpha}{\pi} = I
\end{equation}
where $I$ refers to the identity operator.

Can any operator acting on the appropriate Hilbert space be represented in the Glauber-Sudarshan P-representation, and if it can, how to prove that this is the case? (I am especially interested about the representation of density operators)

By the Glauber-Sudarshan representation, I mean the following:
\begin{equation}
\int P(\alpha,\alpha^*)|\alpha><\alpha|\frac{d^2 \alpha}{\pi}
\end{equation}

Both the integrals are over the entire complex plane.

Comment: I have tried doing so, but I am unable to get anything out of it. Please guide me with this; thanks @AccidentalFourierTransform.

Comment: I think my answer [here](http://physics.stackexchange.com/a/240622/50583) has the formulae you want.

Comment: [Optical equivalence theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Optical_equivalence_theorem) .

Answer (score 1):

The answer is no, and the details are clearly spelled out in Glauber's Les Houches lectures (circa 1964). Glauber introduces a "T-representation" which can represent any operator in the Fock space of harmonic oscillator states, a less general "R-representation" which can represent any density operator, and the still less general "P-representation" which can "represent virtually all [states] studied in optics".

Comment: Thanks for answering. Could you please include a link for the same, as I am unable to locate those lectures?